# Nested TransactionScope Philosophy and Required Option

Tags: c#, .net, transactions, transactionscope

It has been my philosophy that any time 2 or more operations, which depend on each other, happen in a scope, they should be in a TransactionScope, even if those individual actions call down to code that also needs a TransactionScope.  It has been my understanding that supplying the TransactionScope.Required option ensures that if a TransactionScope already exists, a new, nested one won't be created, thus solving the problem of having nested scopes ad nauseam.

My question is **"Is there something wrong with this approach and/or will the Required option not ensure the reuse of TransactionScopes as I thought?"**

Here is a sample of the kind of code I would ordinarily write:

```
    public void DoDisparateThings()
    {
        using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
        {
            this.DoThing1();
            this.DoThing2();
            transactionScope.Complete();
        }
    }

    private void DoThing1()
    {
        using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
        {
            // DB operation 1a
            // DB operation 2a
            transactionScope.Complete();
        }
    }

    private void DoThing2()
    {
        using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
        {
            // DB operation 1b
            // DB operation 2b
            transactionScope.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

Legacy code I deal with sometimes places the TransactionScope only at the top of the chain, and often in calling code where it is not obvious why a TransactionScope is needed.  Consider this:

```
    public void CallingCode()
    {
        using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            this.DoDisparateThings();
            transactionScope.Complete();
        }
    }

    private void DoDisparateThings()
    {
        this.DoThing1();
        this.DoThing2();
    }

    private void DoThing1()
    {
        // DB operation 1a
        // DB operation 2a
    }

    private void DoThing2()
    {
        // DB operation 1b
        // DB operation 2b
    }
}
```

To me this makes no sense because only 1 operation appears to happen in the transaction, and other code could unwittingly call any of the private methods without realizing a transaction needs to be used.  **Am I wrong?  Is there something bad about putting TransactionScopes in code any time there are related operations happening that would need to be rolled back if they don't all succeed?**

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong with your approach.

Comment: But note that the way you do this assumes you open new sql connection in DoThing1 and DoThing2 (and maybe even in DoDisparateThings). While in general that's not big issue (maybe little pefomance hit for roundtrip), in certain cases it can escalate your transaction to distributed (google for TransactionScope and DTC), even if all connections are to the same database, which is not good (and might fail if you don't have DTC enabled). Better use one connection for all operations in transaction (if possible of course).

Comment: @Evk - In my case, the management of the DB connections is being handled by EnterpriseLibrary so I can't say if connections are being passed around or created and disposed.

Comment: Well I didn't work with Enterprise Library so cannot advice about that. Still good to know about such behavior, since it might bite you at inappropriate time (like when you deploy to server without DTC enabled), especially if you have no idea how connections are handled in your application.